# Can services run freely when started from BroadcastReceivers in Android O?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have a doubt about the Android O [Background Execution Limits page](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background), regarding the Background Service Limitations section.

In the image below, on the second bullet point, it says that receiving a broadcast like SMS/MMS message puts the app in a temporary whitelist where it's allowed to start services freely, even when the app is in background.

I would like to know: is it true only to SMS/MMS broadcasts or to every kind of them?

My current interpretation is that every kind of broadcast the app receives puts it in the whitelist, so services can be started using [Context.startService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)) method even when app is in background and it targets API 26 or higher.

Am I right? Thanks.

[image: Background Service Limitations section]

Image taken from [this page](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services).

Comment: No, only the methods mentioned here and the receivers you wrote in the question. Not all receivers will trigger whitelisting. Although if your broadcastreceiver does trigger a notification or a visible component (even foreground service), it might get temporarily whitelisted

Comment: I got it, @Kushan. I have a custom receiver that doesn't receives SMS/MMS broadcasts. That receiver starts a IntentService with the standard startService method. The IntentService's job is to display a notification, and that itself is a whitelist case as you mentioned. But starting a IntentService in a BroadcastReceiver using startService is not https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#intentservice-is-subject-to-these-restrictions. So my expectation is to get a IllegalStateException   in that point, but that doesn't happen, and I simply don't know why. Thks for the help!

Comment: Your app needs to be backgrounded for a bit, only then it triggers that exception... My question... Why not trigger the notification in the broadcast receiver itself...

Comment: I thought that too, but there is some additional work done in that service too, it's a legacy code by the way. Well, you're right; if the app is not in background in that process then I'm fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: The phrase "broadcast, such as" in the documentation clearly indicates that some other broadcasts put application on the whilelist. However, I got the `IllegalStateException` in a broadcast receiver receiving `Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`. Weird. @Kushan , what can you say?